# Select rows from one table according to the number of reps of the id in another

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, the users table and the records table, the relationship is one to many.

I want to select users with less than 3 records.

I am trying to use HAVING but it has not worked.

Thanks for the help you can give me.

example:[image]

For example, I would like to get users 2 and 3 since they are the ones that have less than 3 records.

Comment: Please show us sample table data along with table definitions.

Comment: Most likely, you want something like this: `SELECT u.id FROM users u LEFT JOIN records r ON u.id = r.user_id GROUP BY u.id HAVING COUNT(*) < 5`

Comment: Please check the changes

Comment: The query I dropped in the comment about should cover your question.

Comment: What do you consider to be 'r' and 'u'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select u.id from users u left outer join records r on u.id=r.userid
group by u.id having count(r.userid) < 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.Id,u.Name
FROM users u
LEFT OUTER JOIN Record r ON r.User_Id= u.Id
HAVING COUNT(User_ID)<3
```

Use above query to get desire result.

Comment: Sorry for typo you can check now.